# RustでJSONデータをPostする方法

Tags: rust

RustでJSONデータをPostする方法について教えていただきたいです。
以下のURLの方法を試してみたのですが、`post()`および`body()`の引数に変数を入れると、

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

といったエラーが出てしまいます。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。
https://gist.github.com/fredhsu/ae4088f905ac25bfcc04

Comment: 入れた部分のコードも載せていただけますか？

Comment: 問題を再現するソースコードが無いと何も回答できません。エラーメッセージは「十分な情報がないため型推論に失敗した」と言っているだけです。